# How to get a working state machine in F# using functions for representing states?

Tags: recursion, f#, state-machine, mutual-recursion

I'm trying to create a simple state machine in F# but having trouble getting two states with circular dependencies to work.
I have this state factory:

```
open System
let createState produceInput stateSwitchRule nextState = 
    let rec stateFunc() = 
        match produceInput() with
        | x when x = stateSwitchRule -> printfn "%s" "Switching state"; nextState()
        | _  -> printfn "%s" "Bad input. Try again"; stateFunc()
    stateFunc
```

which I use to create two mutually recursive states:

```
let rec pongState() = createState Console.ReadLine "go to ping" pingState
      and pingState = createState Console.ReadLine "go to pong" (pongState())

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    pingState()
    0
```

When invoking `pingState()`and inputting "go to pong" the state is switched to pong. But when invoking inputting "go to ping" a null reference exception is thrown.
Is there anyway around this with the chosen approach or should I model it differently?

Comment: Your sample is not compiling - it gives me Value restriction error on 'and pingState'

Comment: That's odd; I get the same compile error in an fsx file but not in an fs file (added program code to the example above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
#nowarn "40"

open System

let createState produceInput stateSwitchRule nextState = 
    let rec stateFunc () = 
        match produceInput() with
        | x when x = stateSwitchRule -> printfn "%s" "Switching state"; (nextState()) ()
        | _  -> printfn "%s" "Bad input. Try again"; stateFunc()
    stateFunc

let rec pongState : unit -> (unit -> string) = createState Console.ReadLine "go to ping" (fun () -> pingState)
    and pingState : unit -> (unit -> string) = createState Console.ReadLine "go to pong" (fun () -> pongState)
```

`#nowarn "40"` to suppress the warning about checking recursively defined objects for initialization soundness, different type for the nextState function, otherwise the compiler complained about a value being evaluated as a part of its definition, and superfluous type annotations on states because FSI complained about them being inferred to be generic. Lots of complaints ;)

As for modelling it differently - I think I would wrap it in a type instead of using solely functions, it seems more natural. I guess using functions was the whole point here though.

Comment: Thanks! In an fs file the above also works without explicitly specifying the return types of pongState and pingState, no idea why it differs between fs and fsx,

Comment: In an fs file there's enough of a context to infer the concrete types of those states. That's often not the case when you try out stuff in fsi. If you had a function defined later on in fsx that uses those states, so that the types could be inferred from it, you could drop the annotations in fsx as well.

Comment: I see, but what's in the fs-context with respect to type inference that's missing from the fsi-case?